# Is there a fixed point theorem I can use here?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $A$ be the following set of 2-dimensional functions of one variable with strictly increasing and continuous components:
$$A = \{(x_1(\cdot), x_2(\cdot)): x_i: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x_i(\cdot) \text{ is strictly increasing and continuous} , \qquad 0 \leq x_2(t)-x_1(t) \leq \delta, \\
x_1(0)=0, \, x_2(0)=\delta, \, x_2(1)=a, \, x_1(c)=a-\delta \}$$ 
for some known $\delta >0$, $a>\delta$ and $c \in (0,1)$.

I have a system the maps 2-dimensional functions $(x_1(\cdot) ,x_2(\cdot))$ defined on $[0,1]$ into 2-dimensional functions $(y_1(\cdot), y_2 (\cdot))$:
\begin{align*}
y_1(t)&=F_1(x_1(t),x_2(t)), \\
y_2(t)&=F_2(x_1(t),x_2(t)),
\end{align*} 
for $t \in [0,1]$. I can show that $(F_1,F_2)$ maps $A$ into $A$.

Is there a fixed point theorem I can use here to show that $(F_1, F_2)$ has a fixed point?

P.S. I can show that even if I take non-decreasing continuous functions $x_1$, $x_2$, their respective images $y_1$ and $y_2$ are going to be strictly increasing continuous functions. However, I cannot relax the continuity condition.

Comment: You might look at the Schauder fixed point theorem. It doesn't apply directly because $A$ is not a vector space, but you may be able to get it to work.

Comment: Schauder might not work directly, since $A$ does not seem to be compact in the maximum norm. Try for example $x_1(t)=(n+\delta)t$ and $x_2(t)=nt$. Maybe you can change the metric and/or modify $A$. Here is a theorem which might give you the needed compactness https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem

Comment: I know I don't have compactness here in a usual metrics but I thought monotonicity of functions in $A$ could help somehow.

Comment: What if $F_1(a,b)=a+1$ and $F_2(a,b)=b+1$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You are right... I edited my question (by editing $A$) -- in the model I am considering functions also satisfy certain boundary conditions.